# Meteor: Template is not Showing Values From MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor

Note: Whole code can be found here:

https://github.com/Julian-Th/crowducate-platform/tree/feature/courseEditRights

My JS:

```
Template.myCourses.events({
    'click .js-create-course': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Router.go("/teach");
    }
});

Template.myCourses.helpers({
    'courses': function(){
        return Courses.find();
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<template name="myCourses">
  <button class="btn btn-primary js-create-course"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create a Course</button>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
      <ul class="thumbnails list-unstyled">
          {{#each courses}}
          <li>{{title}}</li>
          {{/each}}
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : "cCoTHJwLTQWgijKKH",
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "coverImageId" : "DJEdLMo8ESXGJkryo",
    "author" : "Test Author",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "some tags", 
        "another tag"
    ],
    "published" : "true",
    "about" : "Testing the Course",
    "canEditCourse" : [ 
        "User1"
    ],
    "createdById" : "MzmPEQPXyawpBHwiE",
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2015-12-26T11:16:19.104Z")
}
```

Collection is defined as:

```
Courses = new Mongo.Collection("courses");
```

I don't get any error messages from Meteor (neither client nor server).

Comment: do you have data available on the client? check with console

Comment: After a review of your code, I can confirm @MarkUretsky's assumption. You can fix this error by subscribing to your `courses` publication with: `Meteor.subscribe("courses");`.

Comment: that was the case @MatthiasEckhart: cheers.